# Bootstrap thumbnail - Center contents (img + caption) with caption float:left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, center

**Hi,**

**Here is what i'm trying to do :**

Center the content: (img + caption) of each Thumbnail. 
*My img must be span3 and the caption must be span4.*

**Here is my problem :**

I can get the content center, or the caption float next to the img;
**But i can't get both at the same time.**

*I started to use bootstrap this morning, so i guess i'm using some class the wrong way.*

**Here is my code :**

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span12">
        <div class="thumbnail span12">
            <img class="span3" data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200">
            <div class="caption span4">
                <h3>My Title</h3>
                <p>blabla</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slake, from my little experience with bootstrap, you have to create a containing div to setup the overall layout. Take a look at the bootstrap documention - layout section [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html). e.g.,

```
<!-- wrap your twitter stuff in -->
<div class="container"></div>
```

Also, take a look at this very helpful [w3resource tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/thumbnails-tutorial.php) to create thumbnails with twitter bootstrap. Following this tutorial I was quickly able to create a basic example of the thumbnail grid you're trying to setup. You can fiddle with the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SJHce/2/).

Copying a part of the example code (more in the link above):

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span12">
           <div class="thumbnail">
               <div class="span3 offset2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/5" alt="300x200"></div>
            <div class="span5">
                <h3>My Title</h3>
                <p>blabla</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Actually, i do have a container (i just copy/paste the part of the code that i'm working on) - looking at w3ressources tuts now.

Comment: You'll have to make a couple changes to make this responsive.

Comment: It seems to be responsive, when i resize my window to what-ever size; it's still keeping proportions - why do you say that it's not ?

Comment: I hadn't tested its responsiveness so wrote the previous to be on the safe side. If it weren't you could've tried the container-fluid class.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Friend:
mey  it can help u :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstap</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
body {padding:20px;}
img {margin:0 3px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="snap4"><img class="pull-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/260x180/ddd/000" /></div>
        <div class="span8 pull-left">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="snap4"><img class="pull-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/260x180/ddd/000" /></div>
        <div class="span8 pull-left">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="snap4"><img class="pull-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/260x180/ddd/000" /></div>
        <div class="span8 pull-left">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not what i'm looking for :(
The same, but my text have to be "span4". And if you change it to "span4", then it won't be centered. Any idea how i can have : span4 span4 centered - Without using offsets ?

Comment: what do u exactly looking for, i mean ur layout ...?

Comment: I'm trying to get my (img + caption) centered and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

also u can use `offset class` to have space for your content, like this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="snap4"><img class="pull-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/260x180/ddd/000" /></div>
        <div class="span7 pull-left">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offset1"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="snap4"><img class="pull-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/260x180/ddd/000" /></div>
        <div class="span7 pull-left">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offset1"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="snap4"><img class="pull-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/260x180/ddd/000" /></div>
        <div class="span7 pull-left">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offset1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i use offset, that's killing the responsive design (if you resize your browser, that will looks not centered anymore)